# How to make appear different labels to different point in the same graphic?

Tags: graphics, labeling

I am having some trouble to make a graph where there are three data points with x-error bars and I wanted to label each point. I managed to make the first label (the purple one) to appear but I didn't succeed with the remaining two, even though the commands I used are the same.

Moreover,I cannot figure out why in the Framelabel (at the beginning) the alpha symbol comes after the "=137 (...)" even though I wrote it in the exact order in the command.

I have followed several tutorials and read lots of answers in different forums but I am not able to solve the problem. Thanks in advance for the help and the kindness!

Have a nice day!

Here is the code:

```
SetOptions[ListPlot, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {Automatic, None}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Black, 
  FrameLabel -> {Superscript[\[Alpha], -1] "= 137.03 \[Times]" \
Superscript[10, 5] }, Mesh -> All];

data1 = {{599.17 \[PlusMinus] 3.676932651, 0.06}};
pt1 = {599.17, 0.06};
g1 = ListPlot[data1, PlotStyle -> Purple, 
   PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers", PlotStyle -> PointSize -> Medium];
label1 = Text[
   Style[Subscript[Superscript[\[Alpha], -1], "QH"], Purple], 
   Offset[{20, 10}, pt1]];
data2 = {{599.29 \[PlusMinus] 0.9922778767, 0.04}};
pt2 = {599.29, 0.04};
g2 = ListPlot[data2, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers", 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize -> Medium];
label2 = Text[
   Style[Subscript[Superscript[\[Alpha], -1], "QED"], Blue], 
   Offset[{20, 10}, pt2]];
data3 = {{599.9084 \[PlusMinus] 0.0021, 0.02}};
pt3 = {599.9084, 0.02};
g3 = ListPlot[data3, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers", 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize -> Medium];
label3 = Text[
   Style[Subscript[Superscript[\[Alpha], -1], "CODATA-18"], Red], 
   Offset[{20, 10}, pt3]];
Confronto = 
 Show[g1, g2, g3, 
  Graphics[{Purple, label1}, {Blue, label2}, {Red, label3}], 
  PlotRange -> {{594, 605}, {0.01, 0.07}}, AxesOrigin -> {594, 0}, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.75]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! You have to wrap the labels in another list to use them in ``Graphics``: ``Graphics[{{Purple, label1}, {Blue, label2}, {Red, label3}}]``. As for the label: Do not simply put the quantities next to each other, because this means multiplication, and Mathematica will rearrange the terms by itself. Put them, for example, in a row: ``FrameLabel -> Row[{Superscript[α, -1] , "= 137.03 ×", Superscript[10, 5]}]``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a single [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

SetOptions[ListPlot,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, None},
  FrameTicksStyle -> Black,
  FrameLabel -> {StringForm["`` = ``", Superscript[α, -1] , 
     137.03 10^5]},
  Mesh -> All,
  PlotMarkers -> ""];

data = {
   {599.17 ± 3.676932651, 0.06},
   {599.29 ± 0.9922778767, 0.04},
   {599.9084 ± 0.0021, 0.02}};

colors = {Purple, Blue, Red};

labels = {"QH", "QED", "CODATA-18"};

ListPlot[List /@
  (Labeled[#[[1]], Style[#[[2]], #[[3]]], Above] & /@
    Transpose[{data, labels, colors}]),
 PlotStyle -> colors,
 PlotMarkers -> Style[○, 14, Background -> White],
 PlotRange -> {{594, 605}, {0.01, 0.07}},
 AxesOrigin -> {594, 0},
 AspectRatio -> 0.75]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your problem was the wrong use of the curly braces in the `Graphics` command. I also changed the definition of labels to be more convenient for me.

```
label1 = 
  Text[Style[Subscript[Superscript[\[Alpha], -1], "QH"], Purple], 
   pt1 + {0, 0.005}];
label2 = 
  Text[Style[Subscript[Superscript[\[Alpha], -1], "QED"], Blue], 
   pt2 + {0, 0.005}];
label3 = 
  Text[Style[Subscript[Superscript[\[Alpha], -1], "CODATA-18"], Red], 
   pt3 + {0, 0.005}];
```

all your other definitions are unchanged. After that:

```
Confronto = 
 Show[g1, g2, g3, 
  Graphics[{Purple, label1, Blue, label2, Red, label3}], 
  PlotRange -> {{594, 605}, {0.01, 0.07}}, AxesOrigin -> {594, 0}, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.75]
```

returns the following:

[image]

Have fun!